# SIEBEL CRM Column ID

Tags: crm, siebel

Currently I am using this approach to get the column ID whenever user drilldowns from a column, [capture drilldown column ID](https://siebelexplored.blogspot.com/2009/09/capture-drilldown-based-on-field.html?sc=1677232451790#c6856408475288483152).

The approach works well with every other applets, but 1. The ID after the substring keeps changing each time I run web client. 1 time its 's_1_2_47' another time it's '2_2_47'. I am not sure which part is causing this cause the code is exactly the same as in other applets that are working.

Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the PM (Presentation Model) of the applet you can create a new implementation for the method "Drilldown" as follows:

```js
function preInvokeMethod(methodName, psInputArgs, lp, returnStructure) {
  if(methodName == "Drilldown") {
    // The Field on which drilldown was done:
    let fieldName = psInputArgs.GetProperty("SWEBCFField");
    // The List Columns Siebel generated name:
    let colName = psInputArgs.GetProperty("SWEField");
  }
}
```

The input argument to the preInvokeMethod function has all the information that you need.